# What is the return type of list<student>?

Tags: java, return

I want to create a method to populate the data of `student` with the method signature as
`public List<student> populateData(String filename)`.

I am new in Java. Can anybody help me with this?

Code implemented by me is

```
public List<Student> populateData(String fileName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Participant_Workspace\\Q3\\StudentDataManagementSystem\\StudentDetails.txt‌​"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        list.addAll(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
    return list;
}
```

but it gives error to add `arrayList<string>` and to `list.addAll(s.next());`.

Comment: I just want to read data from file and display it.  but I dont know what would be return type of it.

Comment: If `public List populateData(String filename)` is you method , then `List` is your return type. Please be more specific and do some coding ,then comeback.

Comment: Scanner s = null;
  try {
   s = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Participant_Workspace\\Q3\\StudentDataManagementSystem\\StudentDetails.txt"));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  List<Student> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (s.hasNext()){
      list.add(s.next());
  }
  s.close(); I have done this much coding but stuck as it is giving error to add arrayList<string>

Comment: what is StudentDetails.txt‌​ 's format?

Comment: It is just a list of student with their names and roll number

Comment: Post you code in the question by editing it

Comment: It has a class student which has following attributes as rollnumber,name, age and address where address again have streetname,city and zip code. In this we are having studentDetails.txt which has information like "1,Beena,6,Camp,Mumbai,411045". We have to read that file and populate data in List<student> .In StudentDetail file if integer value is missing for any candidate then we have to print zero else null

Comment: Code implemented by me is  public List<Student> populateData(String fileName) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  Scanner s = null;
  try {
   s = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Participant_Workspace\\Q3\\StudentDataManagementSystem\\StudentDetails.txt"));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
  while (s.hasNext()){
      list.addAll(s.next());
  }
  s.close();
 
  return list;
 } but it gives error to  list.addAll(s.next());

Comment: @ Sagar Please edit your Question by adding your code.

Comment: Please read the JavaDoc of [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and [`List#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29). You will see, that `next` returns `String` and `addAll` expects a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is is something like this.

> abc 101
>
> xyz 102
>
> pqr 123

Below Given is a simple example, make alterations and do your stuff.

```
public class PrintStudentsFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


     List<Student> students= new PrintStudentsFromFile().populateData("path to text file");


     for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Reads Files and returns a List of Students
     * @param filename
     * @return 
     */
    public List<Student> populateData(String filename){
    Scanner s = null;
    String nameAndRollNumber="";
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
        nameAndRollNumber = s.nextLine();
        String[] nameAndRollNumbers = nameAndRollNumber.split("\\s+");
        String name = nameAndRollNumbers[0];
        String roll = nameAndRollNumbers[1];
        list.add(new Student(name, roll));
        }
        s.close();
        return  list;
    }

}
/**
 * 
 * Student Object , with name and Roll Number Params
 */
class Student{

    String name;
    String rollNumber;

    public Student(String name, String rollNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public void setRollNumber(String rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name :"+name+"- Roll Number : "+rollNumber;
    }


}
```

Comment: We cannot add new method like getStudent

Comment: but how can i replace getStudent

Comment: edited my answer , but tell me why **you cannot add new method like getStudent**

Comment: These are the methods provided for assignment and we cannot even change a word. :(

Comment: Hi,Sagar ,if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: What if one of the field in file is empty? for example rollno field is empty it should print "0" with respective name and other records. Please help

Comment: use an `if` statement , like `if(rollno.equals("")){rollno="0"}`.